# Lotus Web Form Scroll and Popup issue

Tags: scroll, lotus-notes, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to create a web form in Lotus Notes that is web enabled.  So far this has all worked fine, however there are 2 issues.

1. When Creating a Java Script Alert in the OnLoad Event, it Pops up everytime a user selects a radio button or dropdown option since this reloads the page.  Is there any way to make this only for the initial opening of the form?
2. When a user selects an option, the form reloads and puts that form field on the top which is proving to be very disorrienting for users.  Is there a way to have it not scroll on reload?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best advice would be: use XPages for web development that is "state of the art". If you can't, you have to code a lot of JavaScript to make the form not behave like "havoc".

First of all: the field property "refresh fields on keyword change" is the reason for the jumping / reload.
What does domino do? 
All events / formulas that occur when you normally press F9 or use the Option above (that can be field values, input translations, hide whens, etc.) are not "converted" to HTML and javascript but are executed by the server. Therefor each change in a field with the option set submits the form and adds an &Seq=x to the url to keep track of the state. X increments on every reload. Of course this reload causes all events to be triggered again.

For you this means:

1. Option
   disable the option to reload the form after keyword change.
   Unfortunately you have to recode every dependency / calculation / hide when with javascript. Using a framework like jquery or dojo this is possible, but a lot of work.
   If there IS no dependency then just disable the option...
2. Option
   Live with the "jumping" and let your onload event check for the existance of an URL- parameter called seq... And only if it does not exist, then it is a "real" OnLoad...

Both options are not quite nice and not very easy to code...
That's one reason why IBM started XPages... There all this stuff is already handled by default...

Comment: Nice answer. But [it's "XPages" and not "xPages" or anything else](https://twitter.com/XPages/status/354259532530200576) :)